# How to make this layout so the textarea is not pushed to the next line?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple layout. It has an image and a text area. I would like the image to be in the upper left of the layout, and the text area to be to the right of the image, and aligned with the top of the image.

Instead, the text area is being pushed to a new line. How can I make the the text area align with the top of the image?

```
<div class="image"></div>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea> 

.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.textarea {
  height: 150px;

  margin-left: 60px;
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 60px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 60px);
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't accounted for whitespace. When you make an element inline or inline-block, it flows as if it were text. In other words, whitespace between the elements will be represented. You've added a 10px buffer, but 10px is not enough to leave room for the whitespace. You have two options:

1. Decrease the width of the textarea more. You may have to play around with the value a bit, but eventually, it will go on the same line
2. Leave no whitespace between the elements, i.e.:

   ```
   <div class="image"></div><textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
   ```

Also, right now, it will *never* work because you've added a left margin to the textarea equal to the width you're subtracting. The total of margin+width must be accommodated on the line or it will break to the next line. Remove the margin entirely.

Check out the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fzjadep/. All I did was remove the margin and subtract 100px instead of 60px from the width. Despite what the others are saying, it is not necessary that the textarea also be inline-block.

Comment: well explained answer with actual logic. this is called experience.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Although, simply setting the image to use `position: absolute` also worked. Is your strategy better?

Comment: You're right on not needing to set the textarea to inline because it's already inline. I'm just used to doing it out of habit.

Comment: why unnecessary using `position:absolute`?

Comment: "Better" is relative. However, using `position:absolute` actually removes the element from the document flow. It may work now in this limited scenario, but if the document reflows, the image will remain where it is and the textarea will move away.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>They need to both be set to inline-block</strike> (*as stated above you don't need to set it to inline because it's already an inline element*) and you need to get rid of the margin on your textarea but you are going to have a space between them that is about 4px. In order to get rid of this space you will want to wrap the elements in a div and set that div's `font-size: 0`. Also `vertical-align: top` to make things look nice.

[Here is a fiddle with the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/uusb4hzk/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
</div>

.wrap {
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 150px;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 60px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 60px);
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what floats are designed for.

```css
.image {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.textarea {
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 60px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 60px);
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="image"></div>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```